# c++ get vector by indices of vector by std::transform

Tags: c++

There are two vectors :
Indices vector holds the indices we want to get from dataHolder

```
std::vector<int> indices{ 2, 3, 7 };
```

dataHolder vector holds the data items. Can be of any size

```
std::vector<std::wstring> dataHolder{ L"10 kz", L" 20 khz", L"100 khz", L"1 hz", L"5 hz" };
```

Get result vector from dataHolder vector

```
Example : resultvector{L"100 khz", L"1 hz"}
```

It is no problem to write such algorithm using 2 for cycles.

Is there any solution using using std::transform?

For whom it may concern :

Current Implementations

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> indices{ 2, 3, 7 };
    std::vector<std::wstring> dataHolder{ L"10 kz", L" 20 khz", L"100 khz", L"1 hz", L"5 hz" };

    std::vector<std::wstring> result;
    for (int index = 0; index < dataHolder.size(); index++)
    {
        if (std::any_of(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [&](int dataVal) { return index == dataVal; }))
            result.push_back(dataHolder.at(index));
    }
}
```

I think this has quadratic complexity. So i am looking for suggestion with std::transform. If it helps!

Comment: ***How*** do you get the `resultvector`? How are the two elements in it picked from `dataHolder`, and what role does `indices` play? What is your current algorithm?

Comment: Currently i loop over dataHolder items with simple for loop and then find the index in indices vector with another inner loop. That's why i mentioned this can be done with 2 for cycle. resultvector is expected output vector.

Comment: Can you please *show us*? Please create a [mcve] of your current algorithm, how the shown `resultvector` is populated. You have three values in `indices`, how does that translate to two values in `resultvector`? How does the "index" `7` fit in your five-element `dataHolder` vector?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why do you need to use `std::transform` at all? What is wrong with the two loops? And also, what does your algorithm actually do? At first I thought it takes the indices in the first vector and extract the entries of the second vector at those indices. But that would clearly take only a single loop, and also does not match your example (indices vector having three entries, result vector having two). You really should present us with code and then talk about why that code is not sufficient (like "the time complexity is too high").

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Please see the edit for current implementation. I thought this is simple.

Comment: @Aziuth Edited the code with current implementation and why i am looking for std::transform approach.

Comment: Do I assume correctly that the new array has to hold the data in the same order as the old array did? If so, you should state that in particular, especially when your example has a sorted indices vector. If so, you can easily improve the complexity by simply sorting indices (O(NlogN)) and then going through them in order, or by having indices being something like `std::set`, which has a logarithmic search complexity, also resulting in a total order of O(NlogN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see all you need to do is to iterate over the `indices` vector and add the corresponding element from the `dataHolder` vector to `result`.

Something like

```
std::vector<int> indices{ 2, 3, 7 };
std::vector<std::wstring> dataHolder{ L"10 kz", L" 20 khz", L"100 khz", L"1 hz", L"5 hz" };

std::vector<std::wstring> result;
result.reserve(indices.size());  // Pre-allocate memory

for (auto index : indices)
{
    if (index >= 0 && index < dataHolder.size())
        result.push_back(dataHolder[index]);
}
```

No need for `std::transform` or nesting of loops. And the index validity check solve the problem of the invalid index `7` in the `indices` vector.

Comment: Why are you allocating the memory? Isn't it better if we don't? The full capacity may remain unused.

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju Is it higher probability that there will be invalid indexes in the `indices` vector, than there are valid? Even if there is, is it worth the performance penalties of possible reallocations inside the loop? It seems you're interested in performance and efficiency, so why not make it as efficient as possible by trading some memory? And considering that even on pretty ancient computers there's enough memory for thousands of "wasted" elements in `result` the trade-of could be worth it. It's up yo you to decide though.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `std::transform`, but it has to return a value.

In my example, you'd have to remove all empty strings after the transformation, as I return an empty string, if the index is out of bounds:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> indices{ 2, 3, 7 };
    std::vector<std::wstring> dataHolder{ L"10 kz", L" 20 khz", L"100 khz", L"1 hz", L"5 hz" };

    std::vector<std::wstring> result;

    std::transform(indices.begin(), indices.end(), std::back_inserter(result),&dataHolder](const auto& index) {
        if (index < dataHolder.size())
            return dataHolder.at(index);

        return std::wstring{};
    });

    result.erase(std::remove_if(result.begin(), result.end(), [](const auto& result){
            return result.empty();
        }), result.end());

    return 0;
}
```